# KiCad Multiple power inputs

Tags: power, pcb, pcb-design, connector, kicad

I'm working on a project in KiCad.

I have a connector that has multiple connections for GND, +5V, and +12V (all set to type: Power Output) in order to increase the maximum current. However, I don't know how to tell eeSchema that I want to do this.

When I connect them all to `GND`, `+5V`, and `+12V` (respectively), I get the error `ErrType(5): Conflict problem between pins. Severity: error` and it tells me that the power pins from the connector are connected to each other - just the way I want it.

Is it possible to acheive this without editing the connector schematic or should I change the pin types to `passive` for all except one on each plane?

Comment: [Registered as a blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/kicad/+spec/erc-parallel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple power symbols are not there to increase the maximum current. They are used when different parts of your circuit operate on different voltages. For an example you might have a digital circuit that runs at 5V DC, which controls a 12V relay. The  +5V and +12V symbols are used to distinguish between these different rails. 
If you want to increase the maximum current that can be carried in a line, you have to do it in pcbnew. When you route the board, make sure to create a net class for GND and your positive rails, and give them an higher value for track width.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation in ERC. I've filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1469525) for that ages ago, but so far neither I nor anyone else had any time for that.